# LM317T outputs current on Adjust pin with nothing connected between adjust and Vout?

Tags: basic, constant-current, lm317

I have a LM317T-based simple circuit and I'm using a 12V battery to power it. I connected the **Vin** to + 12V and made a constant current circuit [as shown here](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/lm317-constant-current-vs-constant-voltage/?action=dlattach;attach=199033;image). Now, I'm using a variable resistor of 100k instead of a fixed-value resistor and have connected a LED in place of **RL** of the diagram.

Now before connecting the + 12V to **Vin**, I set the resistor value to the maximum, 100k ohms. This is a really large value so the current flow to the LED should be so low that it shouldn't light at all. 
But the LED lights up very dimly. 
And if I reduce resistance on the variable resistor, the LED becomes brighter as current flow increases, as expected.

Even if I remove the 100k resistor and keep the path between **Vout** and **Adjust** open, the LED still lights up very dim. 
Is this normal? Why is this happening? Can anyone explain this behavior of LM317T?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. The internal circuits in any three-terminal regulator require a certain amount of "quiescent" current to operate correctly (some more than others), and this current flows through the "adjust" or reference pin.

When used in a current regulator configuration, this quiescent current becomes the minimum output current. Even "low power" regulators (Iq << 1 mA) will pass enough current to light an LED visibly.

Comment: What could be the voltage between 'adjust' and negative terminal of the 12 V battery in this case? I don't have a multi-meter yet, so I can't measure it for the moment.

Comment: It would be the battery voltage, reduced by the drop across the regulator. In a current source configuration, that voltage drop would be approximately the nominal output voltage of the regulator plus its rated dropout voltage (minimum Vin-Vout).